# How to transfer csv files from GCP cloud storage bucket to a ftp server

Tags: java, google-bigquery

We need to transfer the csv files from GCP cloud storage to a ftp server, how we can achieve this?

Can we transfer this files directly to ftp with bigquery tools?

Or do we need to download it with a service and then upload to the ftp?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Ah... Seems I've missed your `Java` tag. Well, if you're okay with spawning sub-processes, then the following solution should work. Else, please consult the supported Java API for GCP. As of today it's [this one](https://github.com/googleapis/java-storage-nio)

If you have ssh access to your ftp server, then simply use the Google Cloud SDK:

```sh
gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [SAVE_TO_LOCAL_FTP_DIR]
```

Else, the following command pipes data from GCP -> Your local machine -> FTP:

```sh
gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] - | curl -T - ftp://user:PASS@ftp-server.com/filename.ext
```

The first `-` after `[OBJECT_NAME]` tells `gsutil` to write to `STDOUT` instead of an ordinary file, while the second `-` tells `curl -T` to read from `STDIN`. For the uninitiated, the `|` is a bash pipe indicating to pass `STDOUT` of the first program to the `STDIN` of the next.

Comment: Actually we had implemented this without GCP and not tried your solution. But thanks for your help. May be this will help others in future.